# AS3 Objects not being displayed

Tags: actionscript-3, class, flash-cs5

I´m trying to display two movie clips on the scene.
I made an action script file called **main.as** and the .fla file is calling the main class. The button class is a button movieclip.

**This is the code:**

```
      package  {
    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.events;
    public class button extends SimpleButton {


        public function button() {
            // constructor code
        }
    }

}

    public class main extends MovieClip {

        private var button1:button = new button;
        private var button2:button = new button;

        public function main() {
            // constructor code
            button1.x = 550/4*3;
            button1.y = 400/4*3;
            addChild(boton1);

            button2.x = 550/4*3;
            button2.y = 400/4*3;
            addChild(boton2);

            button1.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,pressButton);

        }
        private function pressButton(e:Event){
            trace("Pressing button");

        }

    }

}
```

I don´t know what went wrong, this error pops up in the console:

S:\flash3\Clase2\main.as, Line 24   1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: Event.

Comment: Are these to classes in one file or 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1:

```
addChild(boton1);
```

should be written with 2x 't'

```
addChild(botton1);
```

2:

```
pressButton(e:Event){
```

should be

```
pressButton(e:MouseEvent){
```

and you should import flash.events.MouseEvents

Comment: It should also have a u, button1 != botton1

Answer (score 2):

The error means you need to import flash.events.Event in your class. However you should use MouseEvent in your function instead, not Event.

```
private function pressButton(event : MouseEvent) : void
{
    //
}
```

Comment: Always one step ahead of me @Mattias :P +1

Comment: I imported the flash.events.Event but still I get the same error, and the button is not appearing on the scene >_<

Comment: You need to fix your errors before you can expect to see anything. If you remove the code using the events and then run your swf. Same problem?